# How to set the Limit for Audio Recording By using Audio Recorder Class?

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

Am implementing Audio Recording feature in my application.Through Media Recorder class we can have option called SetMaxDuration(milliSeconds) where as in Audio Recorder class i can't find the limitation time for Recording the Audio.
Kindly help me to do this.

Comment: to stop recording with Audio Recorder class you can use a thread with a sleep time of 1000 ms and get a counter in that which has some max limit and when that limit is reached you can stop recording in thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
handler=new Handler();
 Runnable r=new Runnable() 
{
 public void run() 
{
  recorder.stop();
   recorder.release(); 
  } 

};
handler.postDelayed(r, 60000);
```